# Product Refine filter by categories and regions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently trying to implement the product refine filter by categories, condition, region and price, I took this site http://phpcooker.com/product-search-filter-in-php as a reference . But Whenever I check a box (for example, I check a category with 2 or 3 products that belongs it), it fetches the catId in the URL and the page just refreshes and no filtering is being made. It just regroups the products with same category on one side and leave the ones that do not belong to the category I checked, on the other side.

I have 4 tables
ads table with adId, title, catId, regionId, price, condition, description
category table with catId, catName
region table with regionId, regionName
images table with imageId,adId,path, preview

Sorry for my English but I am in desperate need to find a solution to this.?

Here is my class file

```
public function getAllCat(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY catId";
    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    return $result;

}
    public function getAllRegion(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM region ORDER BY regionId";
    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    return $result;
}
    public function getAllAds(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY adId DESC";
    $result = $this->db->select($query);
    return $result;
}

public function getPreviewImage($id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE adId = $id AND preview = '1' ";
    $image = $this->db->select($query);
    return $image;

}
```

Here is my allads.php file

```
<?php

//declaration array varible
 $filtercategory = array();
 $filterregion = array();

//finding query string value
if(isset($_REQUEST['filtercategory'])){
  //query string value to array and removing empty index of array
$filtercategory = array_filter(explode("-",$_REQUEST['filtercategory']));
 }
if(isset($_REQUEST['filterregion'])){

$filterregion = array_filter(explode("-",$_REQUEST['filterregion']));
}
?>
<main class="cd-main-content">
    <div class="Ads-Container">

            <?php 
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY adId";
                    //filter query start
                      if(!empty($filtercategory)){
                       $categorydata =implode("','",$filtercategory);
                       $query .= " and catId in('$categorydata')";
                      }

                      if(!empty($filterregion)){
                       $regiondata =implode("','",$filterregion);
                       $query .= " and regionId in('$regiondata')";
                      }

                 //filter query end
                    $post = $db->select($query);
                    if($post){
                        while($result = $post->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>

        <div class="ads-column_2">
            <div class="ads-column-thumbnail">
                <?php 
                             $preview = $ad->getPreviewImage($result["adId"]);
                             if($preview){
                                while($rresult = $preview->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>
                <img src="/afro-circle/<?php echo $rresult['path']?>" alt="" class="image-responsive">
                 <?php } } ?>
                <div class="ads-preview-details">
                   <center>
                      <h4><a href="addetails.php?adid=<?php echo $result['adId']; ?>"><?php echo $result['title']; ?></a></h4>
                      <h4 class="">FCFA <?php echo number_format($result['price']); ?></h4>
                   </center>
                </div>
                <div class="space-ten"></div>
                <div class="btn-ground text-center">
                   <a href="addetails.php?adid=<?php echo $result['adId']; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_view">Quick View</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="space-ten"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } } ?>

    </div>          
    <div class="cd-filter filter-is-visible">
        <form>

            <div class="cd-filter-block">
                <h4>Categories <span class="spanbrandcls" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="refine/images/reset.png" alt="reset" title="reset"></a></span></h4>

                    <ul class="cd-filter-content cd-filters list">

                    <?php
                                  $getCategory = $category->getAllCat();
                                  if($getCategory){
                                    while($result = $getCategory->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="filter filtercategory" value="<?php echo $result['catId']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($result['catName'],$filtercategory)){ echo"checked"; } ?> >
                        <label class="checkbox-label" id="Category" ><?php echo $result['catName']; ?></label>
                    </li>

                    <?php } } ?>


                </ul> <!-- cd-filter-content -->                    
            </div> <!-- cd-filter-block -->

            <div class="cd-filter-block">
                <h4>Size <span class="spansizecls" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="refine/images/reset.png" alt="reset" title="reset"></a></span></h4>

                <div class="cd-filter-content">
                    <div class="cd-select cd-filters">      
                        <select class="filter scheck" name="subcatId">
                            <option data-type="sizes" value="">Item Condition</option>

                            <option data-type="sizes" value="1">New</option>

                            <option data-type="sizes" value="2">Used</option>

                        </select>

                    </div> <!-- cd-select -->
                </div> <!-- cd-filter-content -->
            </div> <!-- cd-filter-block -->


            <div class="cd-filter-block">
                <h4>Region <span class="spancolorcls" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="refine/images/reset.png" alt="reset" title="reset"></a></span></h4>

                <ul class="cd-filter-content cd-filters list">
                <?php
                                  $getRegion = $region->getAllRegion();
                                  if($getRegion){
                                    while($result = $getRegion->fetch_assoc()){
                 ?>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="filter filterregion" value="<?php echo $result['regionId']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($result['regionName'],$filterregion)){ echo"checked"; } ?>>
                        <label class="radio-label" for="radio1"><?php echo $result['regionName']; ?></label>
                    </li>

                <?php } } ?>        
                </ul> <!-- cd-filter-content -->
            </div> <!-- cd-filter-block -->
        </form>

        <a href="#0" class="cd-close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</a>
    </div>



    <a href="#0" class="cd-filter-trigger"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Search by:</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Here is my JS

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('.filter').click(function(){
   var filtercategory = multiple_values('filtercategory');
   var filterregion = multiple_values('filterregion');

   var url ="allads.php?filtercategory="+filtercategory+"&filterregion="+filterregion;
   window.location=url;
  });

 });


 function multiple_values(inputclass){
  var val = new Array();
  $("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
   val.push($(this).val());
  });
 return val.join('-');
}
```

Comment: You are passing filter values that are concatenated by a `-` character to your query string: are you sure your PHP code can handle that? Looks like it can't. And that's why. You can always do a console log instead of setting the `window.location` to see the URL if it is the way you expected.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are saying but I don't really know JS. I was just following a sample that I found on the internet but it didn't work

Comment: Of course it wouldn’t work. The values in your query string is not understood properly by PHP.

Comment: ok I see. Please any suggestion on how I can correct it? I really in deep need to solve this